# Use nest-keycloak-connect with Client Id and Secret approach

Tags: nestjs, keycloak

New to keycloak, was able to get access_token with Client Id and Secret setup as credentials for a client but backend side always gives me:

`WARN [Keycloak] Cannot validate access token: Error: Grant validation failed. Reason: failed to load public key to verify token. Reason: Expected "jwk" to be an Object`

Digged a bit into it and found that it tried to find a matching kid from the list of kids returned by the `/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs`

Checked that the `kid` in the jwt.headers(from the access_token i passed) indeed does not exist in the kids list provided by the `/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs`  response.

Is there a way to add the kid into the list to make it available for on the nestjs backend?

What would be suggested here? Forget about this credentials type?

Thanks in advance, any suggestions would be appreciated.